# awk - Sort a string alphabetically and remove duplicates within the string

Tags: bash, awk

awk novice here, was wondering if this is doable.

My file:

```
CCDDBBAA 
EFGHAC 
KJLDFU
ABBAAC
```

Desired output:

```
ABCD
ACEFGH
DFJKLU
ABC
```

I want to sort the strings in my file alphabetically and remove the duplicates within the string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perl:

```
perl -pe '%x = map {$_=>1} split ""; $_ = join "", sort keys %x' file
```

or ruby:

```
ruby -pe '$_ = $_.chars.uniq.sort.join("")' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & sort):

```
sed 's/\s*/\n/g;s/.*/echo "&"|sort -u/e;s/\n//g' file
```

Remove white space and separate each character by a newline. Sort the lines generated removing duplicates. Remove the introduced newlines.

Comment: Well done, but I think you could explain a bit more -- that you are using the `e` GNU `sed` extension to execute shell commands, and the original newlines are preserved automatically by `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

With gawk:

```
 awk -v FS="" '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if ($i in a == 0){
            a[$i]
        }
    };
    d=asorti(a,b);
    for(x=1;x<=d;x++){
        printf "%s",b[x]
    };
    print "";
    delete a;
    delete b
    }'
```

Comment: Thanks. Modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk 4.* for `sorted_in` and splitting a record into characters when FS is null:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=ORS=""; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]
    for (i in a) print i
    print RS
    delete a
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ABCD
ACEFGH
DFJKLU
ABC
```